# How To Manage VS C# Assemblies using the ReferencePath Property (Across Developers Within One Company)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, package

I improted a Project and was missing References.
I found useable Assembles and used them, changing the [HintPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817675.aspx) to my local requirements. The next guy will run into the same Problem and possibly change the [HintPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817675.aspx) again.

One way seems to be setting the [ReferencePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882038/hintpath-vs-referencepath-in-visual-studio).
This is where I got stuck.

Suppose I had the following Project:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    }
}
```

On my System this Project depends on `D:\Include\C#\` `Prism4.1Sources\Bin\Desktop\` `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll`

What I want to end up with is `($Libraries)($Prism4_1)Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll`

Where `Libraries` is (`D:\Include\C#\`) my local machine environment.
Where `Prism4_1` is (`Prism4.1Sources\Bin\Desktop\`) the path to prism, constant across developers.

I found different approaches online ([a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229986/how-to-stop-visual-studio-from-updating-assembly-references), [b](https://www.nuget.org/)) and I would be happy to collect them here.
However this is not meant to be a discussion on the topic in general, this is meant to be about the ReferencePath Property.